# Course in advanced syntax (generative grammar)

Tags: syntax, reference-request, generative-grammar

I wonder if there are any good online courses in advanced syntax (within GG framework). By advanced I mean beyond introductory level like Carnie's Syntax or Radford's Minimalist Syntax books. There is MIT online course but they only have PDF handouts that are pretty hard to follow without teacher's comments.

Comment: 'Advanced courses' in syntax centre around certain topics most of the time. Sure, there are courses like 'Advanced topics in Minimalism' or 'Minimalism II' at universities, but they mostly just take a number of recently published papers. Once you know what a constituent is, you're pretty much set to just read actual papers and you don't need a textbook anymore – so I guess, maybe, you need to search for specific topics, like "Subject Islands in Minimalism" or the like.